# CSS accordion menu button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hoping to find some help here since i'm new to webdesign.
Just wondering why my accordion button isn't working? 
When clicking inside the .container, it should run my animation and display my `<ul>`.
Right now the animation works, but i can't seem to manipulate my CSS and change `display:block` to `display:none`.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

.links {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script>
    function myFunction(x) {
      x.classList.toggle("change");
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
    acc.onclick = function() {
      var panel = getElementsByClassName("links");
      if (panel.style.display === "block") {
        panel.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        panel.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <ul class="links">
      <li><a href="#skills"><span>Skills</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#about"><span>About</span></a></li>
      <li> <a href="#contact"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may helpful

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

.links {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

 
  <script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
     function myFunction(x) {
       x.classList.toggle("change");
      var panel = document.getElementById("links");
      console.log(panel.style.display);
      if (panel.style.display === "block") {
        panel.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        panel.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <ul id="links" class="links">
      <li><a href="#skills"><span>Skills</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#about"><span>About</span></a></li>
      <li> <a href="#contact"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I find jQuery sintaxis a lot easier.

Hope it helps

```js
$('.container').click(function(){
      var panel = $('#links');

      if (panel.css('display') === "block") {
        panel.css('display',"none");
      } else {
        panel.css('display',"block");
      }
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

.links {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>

  <script>
    function myFunction(x) {
      x.classList.toggle("change");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <ul class="links" id="links">
      <li><a href="#skills"><span>Skills</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#about"><span>About</span></a></li>
      <li> <a href="#contact"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```